# Xamarin Android Request to Server is not establishing instead getting an exception?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

**MainActivity.cs**

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Browse);
        button.Click += BrowseButtonOnClick;
    }

    void BrowseButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArs)
    {
        Intent = new Intent();
        Intent.SetType("image/*");
        Intent data = Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);

        try
        {
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Error occured ", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
        {
            UploadFile(data);

        }
    }

    void UploadFile(Intent data)
    {
        ICursor cursor = null;

        try
        {
            Button upButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Upload);

            // assuming image
            var docID = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(data.Data);
            var id = docID.Split(':')[1];
            var whereSelect = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Id + "=?";
            var projections = new string[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data };
            // Try internal storage first
            cursor = ContentResolver.Query(MediaStore.Images.Media.InternalContentUri, projections, whereSelect, new string[] { id }, null);
            if (cursor.Count == 0)
            {
                // not found on internal storage, try external storage
                cursor = ContentResolver.Query(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, projections, whereSelect, new string[] { id }, null);
            }
            var colData = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data);
            cursor.MoveToFirst();
            var fullPathToImage = cursor.GetString(colData);
            string fpti = cursor.GetString(colData);

            //Toast.MakeText(this, fullPathToImage, ToastLength.Long).Show();

            // Log.Info("MediaPath", fullPathToImage);

            //var client = new HttpClient();
            //Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fullPathToImage)); //uri.Path
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int n;
            while (-1 != (n = fis.Read(buf)))
                baos.Write(buf, 0, n);

            byte[] vBytes = baos.ToByteArray();

            ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(vBytes);
            //var UploadServiceBaseAddress = "http://192.168.3.157:81/Values/UploadFile?file=";
            //StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(UploadServiceBaseAddress, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(vBytes);

            string strb64 = Convert.ToString(base64);



            upButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
           {
               ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
               progressDialog.SetTitle("Please wait...");
               progressDialog.SetCancelable(false);

               Task.Run(async () =>
               {
                   try
                   {
                       RunOnUiThread(() =>
                       {
                           progressDialog.Show();

                       });


                       string dataUsed = await SendReceiveTest.Test(strb64);

                       string me = "Uploading...";
                       Toast.MakeText(this, me, ToastLength.Long).Show();

                       RunOnUiThread(() =>
                       {

                         progressDialog.Dismiss();

                       });

                       string msg = "Upload Completed";
                       Toast.MakeText(this, msg, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                       Toast.MakeText(this, dataUsed, ToastLength.Long).Show();

                   }

                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       Log.Error("MediaPath", ex.Message);
                   }


               });



           };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("MediaPath", ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cursor?.Close();
            cursor?.Dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

}

**SendReceiveTest.cs**

```
public static async Task<string> Test(string data)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    var uri = $"http://192.168.3.157:81/Values/UploadFile?file={data}";
                    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
                    var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    //Context c = null;
                    //Toast.MakeText(c, stringData, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    return stringData;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("MediaPath", ex.Message);

            }
            return null;
```

**On Exception ex**

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (ReadDone2): ReceiveFailure ---> System.Exception:   at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError (System.Net.WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where) [0x00000] in <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d022f013c1e1>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d022f013c1e1>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult+<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<Complete>b__0 (System.Object _) [0x00000] in <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d022f013c1e1>:0 
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError (System.Net.WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where) [0x0003b] in <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d022f013c1e1>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00058] in <a547bd0d78184f26ab08d022f013c1e1>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x003e6] in <b696532a7c264e5e866cb15a1b40a4a4>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x00449] in <b696532a7c264e5e866cb15a1b40a4a4>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <b696532a7c264e5e866cb15a1b40a4a4>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at XAFileUpload.SendReceiveTest+<Test>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00066] in C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Xamarin\XAFileUpload\XAFileUpload\SendReceiveTest.cs:28 }
```

**On Ex.Message**

```
"An error occurred while sending the request"
```

**On Inner Exception**

*Internal Status* : System.Net.WebExceptionInternalStatus.RequestFatal

*Status* : System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ReceiveFailure

I have a 2 button (Browse , Upload) , by clicking 1st button **Browse** it will pick the picture from Xamarin Android Emulator then after clicking 2nd button **Upload** It send the picture as **base64string** to server by using **SendReceiveTest class** and it's method **Test()** but getting exception while sending the request to server and which is mentioned above.

Comment: Just found why I'm getting that exception it's bcoz the **Base64String** too long so how do i solve it ?

Comment: Took a low resolution picture solved my issue for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intead of converting image to base64string we can send it just like that using WebClient

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {
          client.UploadFile(address, fullPathToImage);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use POST request instead of Get request and you most change your back-end API to receive post request

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            string jsonData =  @"'file':'{0}'";
            jsonData = string.Format(jsonData, data);

            var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var uri = $"http://192.168.3.157:81/Values/UploadFile";
            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

Comment: **Exception :**

 `jsonData = string.Format(jsonData, data);`  __on this code__

`"Input string was not in a correct format."`

Comment: it was because of jsonData string format, I fix it and now will work correctly